# Why is the object returned by `__new__` mutable, even for an immutable base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined a new `float` subclass as follows:

```
class newfloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, attribute):
        r = super().__new__(cls, value)
        r.attribute = attribute
        return r
```

When I instantiate a `newfloat` object, as follows, the `newfloat` object indeed has an attribute `attribute`. For example ...

```
a = newfloat(1, 2)
print(a.attribute)
```

... this returns `2`.

So for some reason, the line `r.attribute = attribute` works, assigning the second argument value to the class attribute `attribute`. But this doesn't make sense to me, since objects of the base type, `float`, are immutable! Why does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the object returned by `super().__new__(cls, value)` is a `newfloat`.  That's why you pass along the `cls` when you call `super().__new__`.

When defining a new class, you'll get a namespace on instances by default ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), ctrl+f for "*custom class types*"), unless you opt-out of that by declaring [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). You can also set new attributes on instances, for the same reason.

```
>>> f = newfloat(1.23, 'ok')
>>> f.__dict__
{'attribute': 'ok'}
>>> f.hello = 'world'
>>> f.__dict__
{'attribute': 'ok', 'hello': 'world'}
>>> f
1.23
>>> hash(f) == hash(1.23)
True
```

As a developer, the responsibility lies with you to ensure that classes modeling immutable types are correctly behaving like an immutable type should.

Comment: The fact that `object` is in the MRO isn't really relevant. After all, `object()` doesn't have a `__dict__`. `float` inherits from `object` too, but `5.3` doesn't have a `__dict__`. `object` is in any type's MRO, but that fact tells you nothing about whether any type's instances will have a `__dict__`.